# Get teams + user capacity/ days off using tfs client library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tfs, azure-devops

I'm looking for a way to get the work capacity and or days off for teams and users using the c# tfs client libraries. I can't find any docs on this!

But I could've been looking in the wrong places the whole time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the code snippet below:

```
String collectionUri = "http://TFS2017:8080/tfs/defaultcollection";
VssCredentials creds = new VssClientCredentials();
creds.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage();
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), creds);
var whc = connection.GetClient<WorkHttpClient>();
var capacity = whc.GetCapacitiesAsync(new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi.Types.TeamContext("Teamproject"), new Guid("Iterationid")).Result;
var daysoff = whc.GetTeamDaysOffAsync(new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi.Types.TeamContext("Teamproject"), new Guid("Iterationid")).Result;
```

Comment: For this I'll also need iteration id's where and how can I get those?

Comment: You can use `var iterations = whc.GetTeamIterationsAsync(new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi.Types.TeamContext("ScrumProject")).Result;` to get iterations id. By the way, you may check TFS rest api, which will get the information you want more easily: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/work/iterations/list?view=vsts-rest-5.0

Comment: When I specify a time frame different as current the call fails! any thoughts why that could be the case?

Comment: Thanks for pointing the issue. I've tested on my side, `timeframe` parameter only works with current. I've submitted a feedback on my side. As an alternative, you could list all iterations to find the id.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I'm doing now. I'm manually checking dates to see if the date is the current one of a future one. All in the past get excluded.